# To Load data coming from server in Tabs

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am getting all the data from server in one shoot in [{}] (format).
Its like

```
[{"id":"1","name":"akash","desc":"desc","category":"Firsttab"},   {"id":"2","name":"ajay","desc":"desc2","category":"Secodntab"}]
```

Right now i am storing data in SQlite & getting all the data from Sqlite in both tabs. Now I need to load akash with desc in first tab & ajay with desc2 in second tab. Help me out.

Coding area

```
 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    List<TabData> tabdata = db.getAllCategory();

    Log.d("TabData", "check: "+tabdata);
    for(TabData tab : tabdata) {

        TabData data = new TabData(tab.getName(), tab.getType());
        tabData.add(data);

        Fragment appFrf = new AppetiserBar();

        adapter.addFragment(appFrf, tab.getName());

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Also

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("PageSelected", "Check: "+position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

And on Fragment getting data as:

```
 List<AppetiserData> rest_list = db.getAllDatarl();

    Log.d("RestaurantModel: ", "Check: "+rest_list);

    cardList.clear();
    for(AppetiserData data : rest_list){
        AppetiserData models = new AppetiserData(data.getName(),
                data.getDescription(), data.getCategory());
        cardList.add(models);
    }
```

Comment: Post your code for both Fragments

Comment: Fragments are dynamic & In coding area section above i have shown the way i am creating dynamic fragments. Rest all code is basic of android fragment

Comment: Its just an example i have taken of two tabs It can be five or ten even dynamically. If there will be 5 tabs i am getting from server then i will get data for all fragments and i have to load particular data for particular fragment. Need an approach to move forward

Answer (score 0):

The data you are getting is in the form of JSONArray. You could parse them in the activity and distribute them in the fragments as you wish. 
To parse them:

```
try {
    ArrayList<String> allData= new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray yourArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray(your json array);
    for(int i=0;i<yourArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject person = yourArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = person.optString("name");//this will return akash for i=0
        allData.add(name);
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I wrote this directly in the browser, but it should work fine.

Comment: No I inserted all data from server in SQLite database first & at fragments i need to get all the data from SQlite Database only . No API call on Fragments